# How I can create a log for web services in a dynamic web project in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, logging

I'm having a problem creating my own logs for a application that I'm developing in my work, the next code that I have works perfectly running in a single class method with Main.

```
    try {
          LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
          Logger logger;
          FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(fileLogger,true);

          logger = Logger.getLogger(fileLogger);

          lm.addLogger(logger);
          logger.setLevel(level);
          fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
          logger.log(level, message);
          logger.addHandler(fh);

          fh.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception thrown: " + e);
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But, when I want to call this function in a doGet webService, the log is appended in the catalina log and not in the one that I'm creating. I know that the catalina appends all the information of the call to the webservice but, how I can to create a new log for certain calls that I want?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at logging frameworks like log4j and logback which gives you lot of flexibility in logging. I used log back to create my own log files.

Comment: slf4j is also worth mentioning.